# Getting error while searcing for an element through .IsElementPresent Selenium in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm finding the trouble while using the ".IsElementPresent" feature in VBA Excel.

Well Actually I wanna to run a query that, In a loading page on Chrome Browser, if XYZ element will not Found or Present then Do Process 1 else Do Process 2

But I'm not able to set the Proper Syntax.

Every time I'm getting an error

> Object Not Found

Here is the piece of my code:

```
If bot.IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]"), 1000) Then
    Application.SendKeys ("~")
    bot.wait 2000
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rng, 3).Value = "YES"
    rng = rng + 1
    wait = 2
Else
    GoTo bypass
End If
```

Here I have tried different task and still getting an error. Can anyone please tell me why I'm getting this?

[image: Error Code]

[image: After Debug]

Please help me with this issue guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. One of a guy from GitHub forums had given me an idea to solve the query.

Here's is the code:

```
Sub iselementpresenttest()

    Dim bot As New WebDriver
    
    bot.Start "chrome", "https://www.google.com"
    bot.Window.Maximize
    
    bot.Get "/"
    
    If bot.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[2]").Count > 0 Then
        bot.Quit
        MsgBox "Yes, Available"
    Else
        bot.Quit
        MsgBox "Not Available"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

What Exactly I'm trying with above code is,

1. Opening the Browser
2. Maximising the browser Window
3. Run to the Google.com Address
4. And want to find the weather "I'm Feeling Lucky" button is present or not
5. I got the message box with a quote, "Yes, Available"

It is working for me. Let me try more tasks! Suggest me more possibilities.

And,

I found the following piece of code very important while achieving this task.

> .Count > 0
>
> and the plural form "Find**ElementsBy**Xpath" of "Find**ElementBy**XPath" instead!

Thank You.