# Close popup if existing on the web page

Tags: html, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the data from a website. The web page may pop up a security dialog box before the login page.

I tried to close the dialog box with

```
Dr.FindElementByCss(".pa.pa-times").Click
```

In some cases it doesn't show the popup dialog box then my above code is throwing an error.

If the popup dialog box does not exist it should continue with the next line of code.

```vb
Sub abc()

    Dim Dr As New Selenium.EdgeDriver
    Dr.Get "url.com"

    Dim Dia As Object
    Set Dia = Dr.FindElementByCss(".pa.pa-times")
    If IsObject(Dia) Then
        Dr.FindElementByCss(".pa.pa-times").Click
    Else
    End If
    '------------------------
    other line of code continues
    '------------------------ 

End Sub
```

Html code for your reference.

```html
<div class="row announcements-row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 right-col">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h2 class="modal-title">
                            Password Security Improvement
                            <span class="close-modal" onclick="loginAnnouncement()"><span><i class="pa pa-times"></i></span></span>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ****abc****. <br>
                            <ul>
                            <li>Can't login? </li>
                            </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if element exist before clicking it.

The line that get the error is

```
Dr.FindElementByCss(".pa.pa-times").Click
```

The problem is that using `IsObject` doesn' t help you to avoid the error if the element is not on the page. `IsObject` only checks if it is an Object and returns true even if the object is Nothing and you previously declared it as object.
You can solve it checking if the object is present with `IsElementPresent` and its XPath like that:

```
If Dr.IsElementPresent(By.XPath("(.//*@class=""pa pa-times""])[1]")) Then
    Set Dia = Dr.FindElementByCss(".pa.pa-times")
    Dr.FindElementByCss(".pa.pa-times").Click
End If
```

Remember to declare `By` as `Dim By As New By` at the beginning of your code.
So if the element is present it will click on it or it will continue.

Comment: I declared variable web driver (Dim Dr As New Selenium.EdgeDriver)

Comment: This is for Selenium Chrome but it should work:
If Dr.IsElementPresent(By.XPath("(.//*[@class=""pa.pa.times""])[1])) Then
Before the click execution and remove the Set Dia and IsObject check

Comment: MrHim, yes as you said that worked fine, but some cases i don't get that popup dialog box, then the above like is checking for that class attribute, hence it throws error..

Comment: Because you don' t have to check it with IsObject, because it could return true even if the object is not present. Please specify wich line gives you the error, what kind of error and if Dia is nothing when the error occurs.

Comment: Run-time error'7' NoSuchElementError, Element not found for Css= pa.pa-times. This is the error code i see for the line "Dr.FindElementByCss(".pa.pa-times").Click" when dialog box is not found.

Comment: MrHim, thanks for your help in this.. im getting other error on first line i.e., on By.Xpath line. The error that i got is shown in this same forum in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680557/getting-error-while-searcing-for-an-element-through-iselementpresent-selenium-i/49690370)

Comment: However, if you want a fast but dirty solution you can add `On Error Resume Next` before the piece of code i wrote and `On Error GoTo 0` after the piece of code and this does the trick but is a dirty solution as i said.

Comment: Found the error! The class is not `pa.pa-times` but `pa pa-times` check the code i have just edited!

Comment: sorry again for multi-commenting. I forgot to say you that you need to declare `By`. Please add `Dim By As New By` at the beginning of the code and it will work

Comment: Thanks for the help MrHim. I dont know some where it is going wrong. For now I have used the On Error Resume Next.

Comment: You are welcome. if you use the code i have added and declare By as New By, it should work and it is a cleaner solution. if it helped, remember that upvotes are always a good idea :D